# Adding an Object File to JIT and calling it from IR code

Tags: c++, jit, llvm-ir

I created a modified version of `HowToUseJIT.cpp` (llvm version 11.x) that uses `IRBuilder` class to build a function that calls an external defined in an shared object file.

This example works fine (on my system) when the external has an `int` argument and return value, but it fails when the argument and return value are `double`.

The Source for the int case is included below. In addition, the source has instructions, at the top, for transforming it to the double case.

What is wrong with the double version of this example ?

```
/*
This file is a modified version of the llvm 11.x example HowToUseJIT.cpp:

The file callee.c contains the following text:
    int callee(int arg)
    {   return arg + 1; }

The shared library callee.so is created from callee.c as follows:
    clang -shared callee.c -o callee.so

This example calls the funciton callee from a function that is generated using 
the IRBuilder class. It links callee by loading callee.so into its LLJIT.

This works on my sytesm where the progam output is
    add1(42) = 43
which is correct.

If I change the type of the function callee from "int (*)(int)" to 
"double (*)(double)", the program output is
    add1(42) = 4.200000e+01
which is incorrect.

I use following command to change callee.c so that it uses double:
    sed -i callee.c \
        -e 's|int callee(int arg)|double callee(double arg)|' \
        -e 's|return arg + 1;|return arg + 1.0;|'

I use the following command to change this file so that it should porperly 
link to the double version of callee:
    sed -i add_obj2jit.cpp \
        -e '30,$s|"int"|"double"|' \
        -e '30,$s|getInt32Ty|getDoubleTy|g' \
        -e '/getAddress/s|int|double|g' \
        -e 's|int Result = Add1(42);|double Result = Add1(42.0);|

What is wrong with the double version of this example ?
*/
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/LLJIT.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/InitLLVM.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

using namespace llvm;
using namespace llvm::orc;

ExitOnError ExitOnErr;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
void add_obj2jit(LLJIT* jit, const std::string filename)
{   // load object file into memory_buffer
    ErrorOr< std::unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer> > error_or_buffer =
        MemoryBuffer::getFile(filename);
    std::error_code std_error_code = error_or_buffer.getError();
    if( std_error_code )
    {   std::string msg = "add_obj2jit: " + filename + "\n";
        msg            += std_error_code.message();   
        std::fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg.c_str() );
        std::exit( std_error_code.value() );
    }
    std::unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer> memory_buffer( 
        std::move( error_or_buffer.get() )
    );
    // move object file into jit
    Error error = jit->addObjectFile( std::move(memory_buffer) );
    if( error )
    {   std::fprintf(stderr, "Can't load object file %s", filename.c_str());
        std::exit(1);
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
ThreadSafeModule createDemoModule() {
  auto Context = std::make_unique<LLVMContext>();
  auto M = std::make_unique<Module>("test", *Context);

  // functiont_t
  // function has a return type of "int" and take an argument of "int".
  FunctionType* function_t = FunctionType::get(
    Type::getInt32Ty(*Context), {Type::getInt32Ty(*Context)}, false
  );

  // declare the callee function
  AttributeList empty_attributes;
  FunctionCallee callee = M->getOrInsertFunction(
    "callee", function_t, empty_attributes
  );

  // Create the add1 function entry and insert this entry into module M.  
  Function *Add1F = Function::Create(
    function_t, Function::ExternalLinkage, "add1", M.get()
  );

  // Add a basic block to the function. As before, it automatically inserts
  // because of the last argument.
  BasicBlock *BB = BasicBlock::Create(*Context, "EntryBlock", Add1F);

  // Create a basic block builder with default parameters.  The builder will
  // automatically append instructions to the basic block `BB'.
  IRBuilder<> builder(BB);

  // Get pointers to the integer argument of the add1 function...
  assert(Add1F->arg_begin() +1 == Add1F->arg_end()); // Make sure there's an arg
  Argument *ArgX = &*Add1F->arg_begin();          // Get the arg
  ArgX->setName("AnArg"); // Give it a nice symbolic name for fun.

  // Create the call instruction, inserting it into the end of BB.
  Value *Add = builder.CreateCall( callee, {ArgX}, "Add=callee(ArgX)" );

  // Create the return instruction and add it to the basic block
  builder.CreateRet(Add);

  return ThreadSafeModule(std::move(M), std::move(Context));
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Initialize LLVM.
  InitLLVM X(argc, argv);

  InitializeNativeTarget();
  InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();

  cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "add_obj2jit");
  ExitOnErr.setBanner(std::string(argv[0]) + ": ");

  // Create an LLJIT instance.
  auto J = ExitOnErr(LLJITBuilder().create());
  auto M = createDemoModule();

  ExitOnErr(J->addIRModule(std::move(M)));

  add_obj2jit(J.get(), "callee.so");

  // Look up the JIT'd function, cast it to a function pointer, then call it.
  auto Add1Sym = ExitOnErr(J->lookup("add1"));
  int (*Add1)(int) = (int (*)(int))Add1Sym.getAddress();

  int Result = Add1(42);
  outs() << "add1(42) = " << Result << "\n";

  // return error number
  if( Result != 43 )
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you dump the LLVM IR produced for the two versions? It might be clearer that way.

Answer (score 0):

Andrea:

Thanks for asking to see the IR outupt. Changing the example code line

```
   // llvm::outs() << *M;
```

to the line

```
   lvm::outs() << *M;
```

generates this output.

Looking at the output is was clear to me that second sed command had failed.
This was because it was missing a single quote at the end.

When I fixed this, the double case worked. Here is the outptut, including the IR, for the the `int` case:

```
; ModuleID = 'test'
source_filename = "test"

declare i32 @callee(i32)

define i32 @add1(i32 %AnArg) {
EntryBlock:
  %0 = call i32 @callee(i32 %AnArg)
  ret i32 %0
}
add1(42) = 43
```

Here is the output for the `double` case:

```
; ModuleID = 'test'
source_filename = "test"

declare double @callee(double)

define double @add1(double %AnArg) {
EntryBlock:
  %0 = call double @callee(double %AnArg)
  ret double %0
}
add1(42) = 4.300000e+01
```

Comment: There was another mistake in the exmaple. For the `double` case to work, you need to replace `clang -shared callee.c -o callee.so` by `clang -c callee.c -o callee.so`; i.e., the llvm `addObjectFile` does not seem to work for shared libraries ?